# Updating database with datagridview changes

Tags: sql, database, datagridview, sql-update

I have `datagridview` filled from database through datadapter. The problem is that I cant use generated Fill, Update and Delete commands since in my `SELECT` query are two joined tables. I need some direction how to achieve this. I will like to update changes in `CellEndEdit` procedure. Should I fill datagridview with two SELECT statements without joined tables? Or is there some simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UpdateCommand` property of your dataadapter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx) to specify a custom stored procedure (which you must then write yourself) to peform the SQL update

Comment: Can I build SQL update method with QueryBuiler or is it wrong way to do it?